# Select inputs and text inputs in HTML - Best way to make equal width?

Tags: css, xhtml

I've got a simple form like so (illustrative purposes only)...

```
<form>

   <div class="input-row">
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" />
   </div>

   <div class="input-row">
      <label>Country</label>
      <select name="country">
         <option>Australia</option>
         <option>USA</option>
      </select>
   </div>

</form>
```

My layout method using CSS is as follows...

```
form  {
    width: 500px;
}

form .input-row {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    clear: both; 
    overflow: hidden; /* stretch to contain floated children */
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

form .input-row label {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

form .input-row input,
form .input-row select {
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

This all aligns quite nicely, except my `select` element (in Firefox anyway) isn't always the same width as my other `input` elements. It generally is narrower by a few pixels.

I've tried changing the width to a pixel size (e.g. `200px`) but it has not made a difference.

What is the best way to get these to all have the same width? I hope it doesn't resort to me setting the `select`'s `width` individually, or putting them into tables...

Comment: Can I tell you a dirty little secret? I use tables to format my forms. It's just _way_ too easy. But Sssssshh, keep that on the down low.

Comment: In all seriousness, though, have you tried setting margin and padding to 0?

Comment: Paolo, I did originally (and it was easy to make the inputs the same width) but I have strived to do it table less and have succeeded over the last 8 months or so ... this one is just giving me grief.

Comment: I had padding (to give between the borders and text some room to breathe) and when I removed the padding, the difference is less (but then my text is hard up against the borders)

Comment: Oh, I know. I love CSS and I obviously agree with its ideas of semantic relevance and such, but when it comes to forms I just like the flexibility and simplicity of tables. Anyways, I'm not sure why this is happening. Form fields are infamous for just how painful it is to get them to style how you want. Sorry. :)

Comment: I've read that styling form elements (too much) is risky because their look is dependant on the browser, and even the operating system. So I would only style the very basics, if you *need* the input elements to be equal width, and you can do that with tables, I would probably go that way.

Comment: I just tested in each major browser... increasing select set width by 4px had a satisfactory result in Chrome, IE, FireFox and Safari. I haven't yet tried the accepted answer...

Answer (score 167, accepted):

The solution is to specify box model for form elements, and browsers tend to agree most when you use border-box:

```css
input, select, textarea {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

---

There's [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) project that aggregates such tricks.

Comment: Might give this a try... do you have any recommended reading on the subject?

Comment: this worked for me, brilliant. This has been bugging me for ages.

Comment: I don't have recommended reading on this, except between the lines of CSS specification. It defines form elements as "Replaced Elements" and doesn't require browsers to style them, which is where trouble starts.

Comment: You also may want to give the elements a standard vertical-alignment if they are contained within the same element.

Comment: @ErickPetru IE7 doesn't support it, but defaults to something that looks like it, so this rule makes other browsers closer to IE, rather than changing IE behavior.

Comment: For IE7 you could use [box-sizing-polyfill](https://github.com/Schepp/box-sizing-polyfill). Just add `*behavior: url(boxsizing.htc);` after `box-sizing: border-box;`

Comment: Woah, this has made my day!  `+1` for you.

Comment: I already +1'd this answer some time ago. Found my way back to it :)

Comment: If anyone else is scratching their heads trying this with a "search" type input, and not text, be sure to target ``input[type="search"]`` as this defaults to ``border-sizing: content-box`` in some browsers.

Comment: But I don't see the trick in normalize.css https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/blob/master/normalize.css

Answer (score 0):

padding will make the text be closer to the edge of the box.

try setting the margin to 0px, and if that seems right, play around with it (like just setting margin-left only)

Comment: I tried using padding: 0 & margin: 0 with !important on the inputs, selects and input-row div, but it just bunches them up real tight. The select box is about 2px narrower (which may have something to do with the border)

Answer (score 0):

Had same problems with 100% width table and cells, with a textbox (also with width at 100%) wider than the table cell.

This solved my problem in the css:

```
table td
{
    padding-right: 8px;
}
```

Not the best solution ever, cause you probably get some additional space to the right side. But at least it's not hiding anymore!

Comment: I'm doubtful about such absolute sizes. If you use another browser, another window manager / windows style, this is likely to not work any more.