# How can I equalize the heights of text input fields?

Tags: css, forms, google-chrome, webkit

What is the best way to equalize the height of my `<select..>` elements and my `<input type="text"..>` elements? It's proving difficult because of differences in box-sizing models.

Google Chrome's user agent stylesheet has this:

```
select { -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; }
```

..whereas other text input fields use the content box model. Why the difference? Should I perhaps make all of my text-based input fields use the border-box model?

BTW, I'm using standards-compliant mode (by using `<!DOCTYPE html>`).

Comment: An interesting question for which I have no answer.  If you get nothing here, perhaps ask again over on http://doctype.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select inputs and text inputs in HTML - Best way to make equal width?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895904/select-inputs-and-text-inputs-in-html-best-way-to-make-equal-width)

Answer (score 3):

Yeah.. this is extremely difficult.
Dont forget that there are issues with firefox treating form elements differently as well.
cross browser form manipulation is impossible at best.  :D

Some things to note.
line-height can't be used on all elements..   ie. firefox hard codes a line height to input[type=text] elements.

I have an article on using inline-block and vertical align, which may help some.. (use verital-align:baseline;)
[The Joys of Inline Block at screwlewse.com](http://screwlewse.com/2010/02/26/the-joys-of-vertical-align-using-inline-block/)

Also keep in mind that many newer browsers have this added chrome to make the form inputs to look more like the OS. (but that looks like a different issue)

Answer (score 2):

How about?

```
select {padding: 1px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just explicitly set the hight of all input and select fields to a specific pixel height using CSS? If it doesn't "look" like the same height because of borders, remove the borders or set them all uniformly in the same way. For example:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <input type=text style="border: 1px solid black; height: 37px;">&nbsp;
    <select style="border: 1px solid black; height: 37px; line-height: 37px; font-size: 28px;"></select>&nbsp;
    <input type=button style="border: 1px solid black; height: 37px;">
  </body>
</html>
```

This makes all three form fields 37 pixels high. Works on IE and Chrome, but I haven't tested it elsewhere.

Alternately, once the page has loaded, loop through all form fields, find the largest one, and set the hight of the others using their style.height attribute.

Comment: The problem is that different box-sizing models treat the concept of height differently, and there appears to be inconsistency across the browsers in terms of which box-sizing models are applied to which controls.

Comment: See my edits. There are ways around what you mentioned, you just have to try different styles.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should use make all "text-based input fields use the border-box model".

This has already been answered in several other SO questions, [such as here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895904/select-inputs-and-text-inputs-in-html-best-way-to-make-equal-width).

The fact that the WhatWG/W3c accepted the current border-box model is odd enough.
That they haven't done it consistently is even odder.

There is nothing wrong with overwriting the defaults to create a consistent design.
There is no other solution that is as reliable or as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm off base but have you tried using line-height values?