# Setting width of select and input elements in css

Tags: html, css, select, input, width

I'm new to learning CSS/HTML (and to this site!) and am trying to design some basic input fields as practice.

I've managed to set up a few things but am really struggling to set specific width of input/select fields (px is fine but % would be better) using CSS. I am guessing its some kind of specificity issue but just can't figure it out. Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.generalcontainer {
    width:65%;
    margin:5%;
    height:600px;
    float:left;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
}   
.generalcontainer > span {
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 4px;
}  
.generalcontainer > span.header {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: blue;
    display: block;
} 
.generalcontainer > span.subheader {
    background-color: gray;
    display: block;
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: bold;
}   
.generalcontainer > span.label {
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: normal;
    display: inline-block;
    width:25%;
}  
.smallentryfield > select input{
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: bold;  
    width: 500px;
    float: left;
    padding: 4px;
}  
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="generalcontainer"> 
<span class="header">Basic Information</span> 
<span class="subheader">Client</span> 
<span class="label">First name</span>
  <select class="smallentryfield">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option selected="selected" value="Mr">Mr</option>
    <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>    
  </select>
  <span class="label">First name</span>
  <input type="text">
  </input>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your select input CSS selection was almost there, but for yours, it was looking for:

```
/**
 *  Find class of .smallentryfield,
 *      child element of .smallentryfield ( The: > )
 *         find <select> (with .smallentryfield as parent)
 *            find input (with <select> as parent)
**/
.smallentryfield > select input {
   //..
}
```

Despite it went through the whole selection process above, the trouble is - it will ***only*** modify and select the `<input>` at the end of the chain. Instead:

```
/**
 *  Find a <select> class with .smallentryfield
 *    or (Hence the , )
 *  Find an <input> with a parent of .genercontainer
**/
 select.smallentryfield, .generalcontainer input {
     color: #000000;
     font-weight: bold;  
     width: 97%;
     float: left;
     padding: 4px;
 }
```

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/TnQky/1/

You may also notice in the Fiddle the `<select>` and the `<input>` are different widths, you can adjust this with [`box-sizing:content-box;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073768/how-to-get-equal-width-of-input-and-select-fields/4073861#4073861) on the `<select>` element

Comment: That fixes that issue perfectly - I went a bit overboard with the > tags.

I now have a new issue - the second input field doesn't quite fit the row. I've tried removing padding, borders, trying the box-sizing tags but still can't get it to work.

I've made a jsfiddle of progress http://jsfiddle.net/ZxRAu/ (how cool is that site!?).

Sorry to be a pain - any help appreciated again.