# Set equal width of select and input elements in CSS

Tags: html, css, layout

I have noticed something funny when setting widths (200px each in this case) of certain elements in CSS, namely the 'select' element in a form.  It seems that the select element is always a bit too narrow and so the inputs in my forms aren't uniform.  Here is an example (the screenshot is from chrome, but this happens in IE as well).

[image]

The css is like so:

```
input { width: 200px; }
select {width: 200px; }
```

And the associated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/73cQc/)

It doesn't really bother me that much, but is there anything I can do to reliably solve this problem?

Comment: FYI - the different browsers are notoriously inconsistent on form elements like `select`. If you get it right on one, it'll still look a bit off to many users.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/4073861/2806497

Comment: my ocd is killing me.

Comment: This is not for particular issue, but generally css reset is good way to reduce browser incompatibility: http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Select sizing differs from inputs sizing because of different box-sizing. Input has box-sizing set to "content-box" while select has box-sizing set to 'border-box'.
The solution is to specify box model like this:

```
input, select{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: For the record, I also got this to work without "-moz-box" and "-webkit-box".