# HTML <Select> width not equal to other controls

Tags: html, css

I have a Select field that I want to take up as much space as every other field in my form, and they go down vertically.
When I set the width of my controls to 70% all controls assume this width, except Select.

HTML

```
<div>
<ul class="flex-container">
    <li class="flex-item">
        <input type="date" id="dateField" /> 
    </li>
    <li class="flex-item">
        <select type="text" id="areaField">
            <option value="">   Choose</option>
            <option value=" 1">  1</option>
            <option value=" 2">  2</option>
            <option value=" 3">  3</option>
            <option value=" 4">  4</option>
        </select>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#dateField, #areaField{
   width: 70%;
}

.flex-container {
      list-style: none;
}
```

You can see a JSFiddle Demo of what I mean [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xneao4sw/).

Does anyone know what to do about that :)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to invoke the `box-sizing` property and set it to `border-box`.

There are some [good discussions about this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073768/how-to-get-equal-width-of-input-and-select-fields) on a previous thread. The suggested answer of `content-box` doesn't work unless you have a border surrounding the input/select, so `border-box` will work better for you in this situation.

```css
#dateField, #areaField{
    width: 70%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex-container {
   list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <ul class="flex-container">
        <li class="flex-item">
            <input type="date" id="dateField" /> 
        </li>

        <li class="flex-item">
            <select type="text" id="areaField">
             <option value=""> Choose</option>
             <option value=" 1">1</option>
                <option value=" 2">2</option>
                <option value=" 3">3</option>
                <option value=" 4">4</option>
            </select>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @user3307017 No problems!