# same size (widthxheight) for input and select

Tags: html, css

How can I create input[text] and select of same height and width. It shld be same in all browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First [reset your css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

```
input { border:1px solid #333; width:200px; height:30px;}
select { border:1px solid #333; width:200px; height:30px;}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895904/select-inputs-and-text-inputs-in-html-best-way-to-make-equal-width

Answer (score 2):

The tags `input` and `select` don't take the font styling from body, you have to set up the same style for them, for example:

```
input, select {font-family:sans-serif;}
```