# Issue with Input & Select tag height in form

Tags: css

I am making a form. When I give the same height and width to `<input>` and `<select>` tags, the `<select>` tag is not taking the same height as the `<input>`.

There seems to be one pixel difference in height.
What's the problem?

```css
input {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

select {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  vertical-align: top;
}

option {
  color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<select>
  <option>first option</option>
  <option>second option</option>
</select>
```

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RCnQa/12/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select inputs and text inputs in HTML - Best way to make equal width?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895904/select-inputs-and-text-inputs-in-html-best-way-to-make-equal-width)

Comment: In the fiddle the difference is of 3 pixels because of different font-sizes in select and input box. However when you set them equal the difference of 1 px still persists.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You have to give height to your `select` & give `box-sizing` property for this also.

```
select {
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    vertical-align:top;
    height:20px;
}
input, select{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/RCnQa/16/

Works on IE8 & above.

Comment: Should probably also set `margin: 0`, the default margins are different. http://jsfiddle.net/RCnQa/18/

Comment: it's better you can define reset CSS

Comment: I'd recommend `min-height` rather than height

Answer (score 9):

try using `box-sizing`:

```
input, select, option {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;  
}
input, select {
    width:100px;
    height:20px;
    border : 1px #ccc solid;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RCnQa/17/

Answer (score 2):

they will never be equal visually, you can update select css using the below:

```
select {
    border:1px solid #cccccc;
    vertical-align:top;
    height:23px;
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend `min-height` rather than height

Answer (score 2):

Here in 2022 we have display:flex solution:

```css
form.flex {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.3rem;
}
```

```html
<form class="flex">
  <input type="search">
  <select class="queryselect">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Go!">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Even on the latest Chrome as of 11/21/17 it still seems necessary to set a fixed height on the select.

I prefer to set a `min-height` because it just feels nicer to me, plus there are all kinds of plugins that can mess with font sizes that you may not account for. This is a little safer to avoid cropping.

```
 padding: .25rem .5rem;
 min-height: 2.5rem;
 font-size: 1.1em;
```

Note: Can reduce vertical padding since we now are forcing a height.

Use ems for `padding` and `min-height` if you want the height to change when font size changes.

Answer (score 1):

Just use form-control class in select if you are using bootstrap.

```
<select class="form-control">
```

Comment: This is the fastest way!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with select box in one of my projects. I fixed it by changing the Arrow of the select box as stated here,

http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/

I hope this helps.....

Comment: This is not a direct answer to the question. The question is clear: How to place the select of equal size? and not how to change the arrow of the select

Answer (score 0):

Using paddings instead of height gives a nicer end result:

```
input {
    width:100px;
    vertical-align:top;
    padding:2px; //or whatever you want
}

select {
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    vertical-align:top;
    padding:2px; //same as above
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
select{ 
  height: 50px; 
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="0">Man</option>
  <option value="1">Woman</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

just set `box-sizing: content-box;` in your `select` tag `style`.