# Select and Input different heights/text indent

Tags: css

On this [page](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/events/2014/February/22/the-brentwood-spring-craft-and-gift-show.html), there's a text indent/white space on the select before the option.

The CSS for both is:

```
input, select {
margin: 0px;
height: 38px;
border: 0;
padding: 0 0 0 15px;
}
```

I changed the default select to remove the FF drop down which may have affected it:

```
select {
border-radius: 0;
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
text-indent: 0.01px;
text-overflow: '';
appearance: none;
}
```

Any ideas appreciated.

Edit: I got the height the same by adding this to the select and input:

```
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
```

PS the question is and was clear, unless you don't speak English.

Comment: Where is the question in this post? Please revise.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issue with Input & Select tag height in form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767612/issue-with-input-select-tag-height-in-form)

Comment: PS! The question is and was **not clear**, regardless of language preferences.

Answer (score 2):

So I got the the PC and checked out the CSS in the developer console:

I found that turning off the `float:left` on the span within your submit button fixed the vertical alignment and height of the items
(Either change the CSS from affecting all `#search-bar span` or add one for `button.span` to `float:none`)

Instead of setting `height:38px` on the select and input, set their padding to something like `padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;` and leave their height at default
That fixes your text alignment problem in firefox
I see you've updated your code - these mods were done on your original so I don't know if they still hold. Might help you along though

(Oh, and your current white-space issue is cause by the `padding 0 0 0 15px;` - it's the 15px that's adding it)

Comment: Sorry, but this answer surely demonstrates a very poor effort into help the user, you just tell him a standard answer. It seems that you don't want to help, but want to be the fastest gun.

Comment: Actually he was asking for any ideas, and adding a css reset is what I would do when faced with his problem if I couldn't see what was happening in firebug. He gave no indication as to what he had tried already, and I thought this could help him with his debugging.

Comment: As I see, the OP seems to already have a css reset in his page: `@import "/css/css_reset.css";`

Comment: At least it contributed to a cleaner question. I would have just commented but at the time did not have the rep to do so. Should I remove the answer?

Comment: The new answer I think it's more accurate and now you're giving a factible option to the OP. I will remove the -1. Thanks for your efforts.