# HTML <Select> is taller than other controls of same designated height

Tags: html, css

I have a problem where the height of my text field and the height of my select box are not the same, when they should be.
Here's what I have:

Html:

```
<div class="content">
    <ul class="flex-container">

        <li class="flex-item">
            <select id="idType">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
            </select>
            <input type="text" id="idField" class="basicInput" placeholder="  Number"/>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 #idType, #idField{
    width:35%
}

select {
    -webkit-appearance: menulist-button;
    height: 3vh;
    color: #969696;

}

.basicInput{
    height: 3vh;
}

.flex-container {
      list-style: none;
}
```

You can see what I mean [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/gx4jqpk7/1/)

The height should be the same, 3vh, but it's slighter tall on the select.
Anyone know how to fix that :)?

```
    box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
```

These seem to do the trick, thanks everyone!: )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the padding and setting the box-sizing on the inputs fixed it for me:

```
#idType, #idField {
    width:35%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding:0;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gx4jqpk7/9/)**

Answer (score 2):

Different input types have different box models.

If you regularise them:

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

...they get the same height

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/gx4jqpk7/10/)

Comment: If you look closely you'll see that they're still not the same size/aligned properly.

Comment: @j08691 but they're the same height, which is what the OP was asking about.

Comment: I agree, but on different sized screens they fall out of alignment. Seems to be affected by padding too.

Comment: they will align if you set the height greater than the line-height http://jsbin.com/zububuf/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Just realised this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get them a little closer in size by changing the attributes from **height** to **max-height**, but they still differ slightly.  Check this earlier post: [Issue with Input & Select tag height in form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767612/issue-with-input-select-tag-height-in-form)