# Why are select elements not as wide as other form elements?

Tags: html, css, forms

If I set a select and a text input to the same width, the width of the select element is always a few pixels less than the width of the text input. This seems to happen whether I set the width in pixels or percent. Does anyone know why? Is there any way to prevent this?

Minimal demo: http://codepen.io/nosecreek/pen/wehKu

*Tested in Chrome and IE7*

Comment: User agent styles like padding, border etc.

Comment: Depends on the style the user has set for the controls. Some users have different user-agent settings that modify the size of the button on the select element, borders on text boxes, etc...

Comment: As far as I can tell it isn't because of user agent styles, as I have reset most of those in my CSS. The two elements have identical font, font-size, line-height, padding, margin, and border-width and render as such. Yet the width is slightly less, and the height is actually slightly more, on the selects.

Answer (score 4):

I think it has something to do with the box-sizing that is rendered. The select visual part is less than the box that defines the width. Include this in your css and it will appear normal.

```
input, select {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

http://codepen.io/joe/pen/taJnz

Reference: [Select inputs and text inputs in HTML - Best way to make equal width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895904/select-inputs-and-text-inputs-in-html-best-way-to-make-equal-width)

EDIT: I figured out why this happens. I think it's because when you designate the width, you are telling it how big the make the internal box, the ACTUAL input area. The textbox also comes with borders as a standard and the borders are 2px each which is additional size to the width of the text area. Adding the CSS above changes how the width is calculated.  When I make the border of the text box 1px, then it was only 2 px larger than the select. This seems to explain it.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the other question. I'm still unsure as to *why* this is happening, except that form elements generally seem to be less stylable than other elements. Your solution works, but is less than ideal because box-sizing: border-box isn't compatible with IE7. I do fear that there might not be any other solution though...

Comment: You could also as another less than ideal solution just make the width of the input items 4 pixels smaller.Maybe it's because when you designate the width in css, you are telling it how big the make the internal box and the borders are 2px each which is additional size to the width of the text area. Adding the CSS above changes how the width is calculated?  When I made the border of the text box to 1px, then it was only 2 px larger than the select. This seems to explain it. I'll add this explanation above.

Comment: The most robust way to do this is to designate the default border width of the input boxes and then made sure the width of each of them accounts for the borders.

Comment: So essentially the inputs, as with most HTML elements, are using box-sizing: content-box, but the select element uses box-sizing: border-box? That may make sense and explain why defining box-sizing fixes the issue.

I'm doing a responsive design using percents, so setting the selects to be 2px smaller doesn't work for me. I've decided to use the css you included above along with [this polyfill](https://github.com/Schepp/box-sizing-polyfill) for IE7 on my current project.

Comment: Still not sure though, as setting box-sizing: content-box; on the select doesn't make a difference.