# Match Width of Select box with Text Box

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Select inputs and text inputs in HTML - Best way to make equal width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895904/select-inputs-and-text-inputs-in-html-best-way-to-make-equal-width)

I have a input box and a select box, I wish to apply the same width for both of them. i.e 200px. I tried using something like

```
<input type="text" style="width: 200px">
<select style="width : 200px;" size="1">
  <option >test</option>
</select>
```

But it seems that the width of them differs, here's the link: http://jsfiddle.net/GdTqp/

Any Ideas on how do we achieve the same width (while keeping the css width common)

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem when testing in different browsers, try using the box-sizing attribute.

```
 box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input {
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}​
select {
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```