# Styling the width my form sidebar

Tags: css

How can I make all the form fields the same size, so it looks much more tidy.

Here is a link to website, its the form on the right sidebar.

http://goo.gl/Wli8w

Comment: Don't just link to a web page that may or may not be accessible in a few months time. Post the relevant code with your question so that it remains useful in the future.

Comment: I agree with @F4r-20. Now if anyone checks the link, there is no problem, all are aligned perfectly. You could use http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I've just fixed this with this code for future reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895904/select-inputs-and-text-inputs-in-html-best-way-to-make-equal-width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a class "`widhtSize`" to all your input, text area and select.
In the CSS add following

```
input[type="text"].widhtSize, textarea.widhtSize, select.widhtSize 
{
    width: 200px; // Change it as per your wish
}
```