# CSS - Same class, but different lengths for textbox / dropdown box?

Tags: css

I am using the same style for my dropdown box, and a textbox, which is working fine, except that they are different lengths, only by ~10px

http://jsfiddle.net/PkWVg/

[image: Wrong length]

I can't seem to get them the same length without using seperate classes for each. It actually seems that the dropdown icon at the end is suppose to be to the right more?

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    width:500px;
}
.form-textbox, .form-dropdown {
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    height: 20px;
    width:100%;
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
    color: #666;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <select class="form-dropdown " name="turnover" />
    <option value="1">Less than £49,999 per year</option>
    <option value="2">£50,000 - £99,999 per year</option>
    <option value="3">£100,000 - £249,999 per year</option>
    <option value="4">£250,000 - £499,999 per year</option>
    <option value="5">£500,000 - £999,999 per year</option>
    <option value="6">£1,000,000 or more per year</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <p>
        <input class="form-textbox ofTextbox" name="market" type="text" />
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895904/select-inputs-and-text-inputs-in-html-best-way-to-make-equal-width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

```
.form-textbox, .form-dropdown{
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    height: 20px;
    width:100%;
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
    color: #666;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box; // Added rule
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; // Added rule
    box-sizing:border-box; // Added rule
}
```

[**<kbd>Fiddle</kbd>**](http://jsfiddle.net/PkWVg/3/)

Comment: I can see in my fiddle!

Comment: Appears that it depends on the browser. -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
worked.

Comment: Yes For mozila it's `-moz-box-sizing` and for webkit browsers like safari and chrome it's `-webkit-box-sizing` :)

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
box-sizing:border-box;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `padding-left:10px` appears to be the problem. If you remove that, the fields are the same length.

Comment: The padding is needed to position the text.